# Add scalars to vtk file (vtk 3.0 legacy) in Python

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I am trying to add a calculated scalar to an existing VTK file.

A simplified version of my code is the following

```
import vtk
import os
import numpy as np

reader = vtk.vtkDataSetReader()   
reader.SetFileName(vtk_file_name)
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
reader.Update()
data = reader.GetOutput() #This contains all data from the VTK
cell_data = data.GetCellData() #This contains just the cells data
scalar_data1 = cell_data.GetArray('scalar1')
scalar_data2 = cell_data.GetArray('scalar2')

scalar1 = np.array([scalar_data1.GetValue(i) for i in range(data.GetNumberOfCells())])
scalar2 = np.array([scalar_data2.GetValue(i) for i in range(data.GetNumberOfCells())])

scalar3 = scalar1 - scalar2

writer = vtk.vtkDataSetWriter()
```

At this point I assume that I need to add a vtkArray to data by using data.SetCell

The problem is that SetCell asks for a vtkCellArray and I have not managed yet to convert my array scalar3 to a vtkCellArray.

Is this the right approach? Any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at vtk.numpy_support or paraview dataset_adapter for converting back and forth from numpy.array and vtkarrays. Actually this simple example could have been done using the calculator or the python calculator (in paraview) or vtkArrayCalculator

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to use cell_data.AddArray() to add your array. SetCell() would actually modify the topology of your data set.

Rojj is correct about using vtk.numpy_support to convert back and forth between vtkArrays and numpy arrays. You can use something like the following:

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support
...
scalar3_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(scalar3)
scalar3_array.SetName('scalar3')
cell_data.AddArray(scalar3)
```

Comment: Thanks Cory. it works. I assume you meant `scalar3_array.SetName('scalar3')`

Comment: Just realized though that I still need another step. How do I add the cell data to `data` so that I can use this as an input for the `vtkDataSetWriter`?

Comment: Oops... edited my mistake. The cell_data is already a member of `data`, so you shouldn't need to do anything before passing it to the `vtkDataSetWriter`.

Comment: One caveat - you will likely be safer creating a deep copy of the output from the reader with

`data = reader.GetOutput().DeepCopy()`

before you modify its cell data. That way, if the reader re-executes, it won't clobber your modifications.

Comment: `vtkDataSetWriter` requires a `vtkDataObject`. The step I was missing was 'data.UpdateData()' to update `data` with the `cell_data` new content and then I can pass the updated `data` to the writer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm confused. `reader.GetOutput()` returns a `vtkDataSet`, but `vtkDataSet` does not have an `UpdateData()` method.